# data type for text formated as.. bold italics underline and other properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, mysql, ajax

I want to save the contents from HtmlEditor(Ajax Control) into a database field.

If i try to save as VARCHAR than error comes as data too long.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Text or NText

Comment: thank you. Another problem is when i try to retrieve the data in reverse i get the error as  System.IndexOutOfRangeException: order at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName) at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.